# Bluetooth/Wifi small network

Tags: android, android-hardware

I want to make an app that connects to devices in the near vecinity and exchanges data.
I want to have **as high range as possible** using the phone's hardware.

1.What can I use and which is better: the bluetooth or wifi?

2.What is the range I can expect?

Comment: WiFi requires an access point. Bluetooth only allows 7 slaves. WiFi has longer range and throughput. I'd say WiFi if Ad-Hoc networking were available out-of-the-box.

Comment: what is this access point more precisely?

Comment: I should correct myself - a router would be required. An access point could be a router that then connects to the Internet through a wired Ethernet connection.

Comment: cant the satelite that gives internet be used for this? or is there a free API I can use for free to send some string data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For relatively small networks (fewer than 8 nodes), [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) would work, but would have very limited range (~10m).

[WiFi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) would be a good solution if you can guarantee that you're going to have a wireless router available to route messages. Currently, Android does not offer an Ad-hoc solution for small networks using standard WiFi. Range of WiFi can differ based on a lot of factors, but you can expect 35-100m.

You should probably take a look at [WiFi Direct](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html) (WiFi P2P). It is similar to Bluetooth in terms of creating a network, but has longer range. It is important to note that WiFi P2P is only supported on newer Android devices (API level 14 and up).